# string always null in selector although not empty -> unrecognized expression/null is not an object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm running against a wall here.
I got a string in javascript and I just want to select the DOM element with the corresponding id. (In this example I need to simulate a click. But hide() doesn't work either...)

```
options.forEach(function(option) {
    if(option){ //not really necessary
        console.log('#'+option);
        $('#'+option).click();
    }
});
```

and it gives me the following out put:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLiK2.png)

Of course, I also tried the javascript method:

```
options.forEach(function(option) {
    if(option){ //not really necessary
        console.log('#'+option);
        document.getElementById('#'+option).click();
    }
});
```

The console result for this is:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9ovs.png)

What's wrong here? I can't seem to select that element (which definitely exists.
Can anyone help?

Greetings and thanks in advance
Mic

Comment: Share your `options` array.

Comment: Your latter won't work as you need to remove the `#` prefix when using `getElementById()`. The first should work fine though. To debug it we need to know the value of `options`/`option`

Comment: It's an array with different ids. In my test case, it's just the 29120.

Comment: But in the console I saw now, that there is an unexpected Symbol right after the number. I need to check out where It comes from... I hope that's it. Thank's for the quick reaction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the problem is your array. Without seeing your array, I would guess that a character in your Array is not working, as it is "unexpected".

Here is a working example, just to show you that it is working

```js
var options = ['29120'];
$('#test').on('click', function() {
  $.each(options, function(i, obj) {
    $('#' + obj).click();
  });
});

$('#29120').click(function() {
  $('div').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">abc</div>
<div id="cde">cde</div>
<div id="">29120</div>
<button id="29120">hide</button>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, somehow, there is a special character in my string.
I'm trying to receive a string like "29120,29121" and then use the split method, to get an array out of it.

But when the string is split, this symbol appears: "29120↵"
And right now, I have no idea where it comes from.

But I keep digging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem....
It's really stupid...

Im my Ajax file, after the ?> from php, where's a line break...
That causes the special symbol... *facepalm*

Sorry to bother you and thanks for the help

Greetings!